# How to train YoloV4 for custom object detection on grayscale images?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I am working with images of text which have diagrams in it. My images are basically black and white I do not see why I want colors in my images. I got some decent results with default settings but I want to test on grayscale Images too. I am using [this tutorial](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/YOLOv4-Cloud-Tutorial) as the base which is by default using `AlexyAB's` repo for `darknet`. I think I have to change the `config` file as:

```
channels=3 # I think I have to change it to 0
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0 # A link says that I have to comment these all
saturation = 1.5 # This on 
exposure = 1.5  # and this one too
hue=.1 # Should I change it to 0 too?
```

But [there is this link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/56552161066/) which says that I have to comment `hue,saturation,angle,exposure` etc. I want to know that:

1. Do I have to save the images as Grayscale in directory or the code will do it by itself?
2. some other configuration has to be changed apart from the setting `channels=1`? Setting `hue` to 0 is also [suggested in this link](https://gitmemory.com/issue/AlexeyAB/darknet/3201/494895594)
3. Do I need to modify some function which deals with loading the images [as given in this link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/56552161066/) as the `load_data_detection` function

Answer (score 0):

Just changing `channels=1` in the config file should work. If not, then comment out other parameters like `angle,hue,exposure,saturation` and try again

Comment: It kind of threw an error when I did that. I think the code which is loading the images is expecting the images to be in 3 Dim?

Comment: What error did you get? Pease post the traceback of the error

Answer (score 0):

There are posts online and on the official repository suggesting to edit the channels, hue value, etc.

Here is what works for SURE (I tried),
For training set, **either take Grayscale images or convert RGB to Grayscale using openCV.**

```
cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

**Train the YOLOv4 AS YOU WOULD FOR RGB**, i.e. without messing with channel, hue, etc.

Note:Don't forget to set the steps, batch size, number of channels, etc. as you would do normally for RGB images, just train the model on Grayscale images instead of RGB.

Few personal observations, theoretical explanation of which I couldn't find:

1. YOLOv4 trained on RGB images, won't work on B&W/Grayscale images.
2. YOLOv4 trained on B&W/Grayscale images, won't work on RGB.

Hope this helps.

Edit: I'm yet to verify whether this would be computationally more expensive than a model trained with reduced channels. Although it has [shown](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/5191#issue-596149602-permalink:%7E:text=when%20I%20change%20%22channels%3D3%22%20to%20%22channels%3D1%22%2C,time%20was%20not%20any%20faster.%20I) not to reduce/improve the inference times.